# Landscape printing of second page from HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to print second page of my html document in landscape. In print preview I got second page in landscape for printing but the content of my "div" is not printing in whole page. Is it possible to resize the div to be on whole page.
This is my html document code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style media="print">

    div.c {
        text-align: right;
    } 

    @page :first{
    size: portrait;
    }
    
    @page{
    size: A4 landscape;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    
    <p style="page-break-before: always;">&nbsp;</p>
    
    <div class="c">
    <h2 text-align: "right"/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and print screen from the the print preview [image]

Comment: try a `width: 100%` on your `c` class

Comment: did you try css - @page { size: landscape; }

Comment: for more details - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size

Comment: @NagaSaiA see line 14 in the code sample, as well as the screenshot...

Comment: if I use only @page { size: landscape; } , then the first page is going in landscape orientation and I want to stay in portrait.

Comment: @John777, did you ever find a resolution? I have the same problem, except my first page is landscape and the remaining pages portrait. It seems to use the first page orientation to determine the dimension of each page. For the second and subsequent pages, if I use `width=100%` the content goes off page. Also, pages break where the end of a landscape page would be.